# PHP: Calling MySQL Stored Procedure with Both INPUT AND OUTPUT Parameters (NOT "INOUT")

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

From PHP I would like to call a stored procedure in MySQL.  The procedure takes input **and** output parameters -- **not** *"INOUT"* parameters.

For a simple example, say I have the following stored procedure in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_proc`(
    in input_param_1 int,
    in input_param_2 int,
    in input_param_3 int,
    out output_sum int,
    out output_product int,
    out output_average int
)
BEGIN
    set output_sum = input_param_1 + input_param_2 + input_param_3;
    set output_product = input_param_1 * input_param_2 * input_param_3;
    set output_average = (input_param_1 + input_param_2 + input_param_3) / 3;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now, from the PHP script/page side, say I have the following variables (we'll call them "proc input variables") that I want to feed to the stored procedure as **input** parameters when I call it:

```
$procInput1 = "123";
$procInput2 = "456";
$procInput3 = "789";
```

Let's say that on the PHP script/page side I also have the following variables (we'll call them "proc output variables") that I want to feed to the stored procedure as **output** parameters to be *set by* the stored procedure when I call it:

```
$procOutput_sum;
$procOutput_product;
$procOutput_average;
```

So, in essence, on the PHP script/page side, what I want to be able to do, in essence *(I realize the following code is not valid)*, is...

```
call test_proc($procInput1, $procInput2, $procInput3, $procOutput_sum, $procOutput_product, $procOutput_average);
```

...and, once called, the following PHP code...

```
echo "Sum: ".$procOutput_sum;
echo "Product: ".$procOutput_product;
echo "Average: ".$procOutput_average;
```

...should produce the following output:

```
Sum: 1368
Product: 44253432
Average: 456
```

One caveat is that, if at all possible, I would like to be able to do this using the MySQLi **procedural** functions/interface.  If not possible, then however I can get it to work is what I'll use.

I have been programming for quite some time, but the PHP language is a relatively new endeavor for me.  I have found tons of tutorials on calling MySQL stored procedures from PHP.  Some are tutorials on calling stored procedures with **input** parameters, some are tutorials on calling stored procedures with **output** parameters, and some are tutorials on calling stored procedures with **inout** parameters.  I have not found any tutorials or examples on calling stored procedures that take **both** input **and** output parameters at the same time, while specifically **not** using "inout" parameters.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to code the parameter bindings (e.g.: mysqli_stmt_bind_param and mysqli_stmt_bind_result) and getting it all to work properly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and I give thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQLi [does not](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php) have any native support for output sproc parameters; one must instead output into MySQL [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) and then fetch the values using a separate `SELECT` statement.

Using the procedural interface:

```
$procInput1 = 123;
$procInput2 = 456;
$procInput3 = 789;

$mysqli = mysqli_connect();

$call = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, 'CALL test_proc(?, ?, ?, @sum, @product, @average)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($call, 'iii', $procInput1, $procInput2, $procInput3);
mysqli_stmt_execute($call);

$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT @sum, @product, @average');
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
$procOutput_sum     = $result['@sum'];
$procOutput_product = $result['@product'];
$procOutput_average = $result['@average'];
```

Or, using the object-oriented interface:

```
$procInput1 = 123;
$procInput2 = 456;
$procInput3 = 789;

$mysqli = new mysqli();

$call = $mysqli->prepare('CALL test_proc(?, ?, ?, @sum, @product, @average)');
$call->bind_param('iii', $procInput1, $procInput2, $procInput3);
$call->execute();

$select = $mysqli->query('SELECT @sum, @product, @average');
$result = $select->fetch_assoc();
$procOutput_sum     = $result['@sum'];
$procOutput_product = $result['@product'];
$procOutput_average = $result['@average'];
```

Comment: While I did end up implementing a slight variation on your example, your information got me going in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: A procedural style version would be nice.

Comment: @Ishikawa: Surely it's not that difficult to convert it?

Comment: @eggyal: not for you, perhaps, but I think it would help a lot of people.

Comment: @Ishikawa: fine, whatever.  See above.

Comment: @eggyal: Thank you very much for doing that. MySQLi can be daunting and I think procedural is easier for beginners.

Comment: what the 'iii' stands for ?

Comment: @ChutipongRoobklom: integer, integer, integer—each character represents the data type of the respective placeholder.  See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

```
 DB::select('call SP_fci_cb_emp_comp_salary_revision_add(?,?,?,@,@)',
                        [
                            $my_compensation['detail']['employee_master_id'],
                            Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $salary_revised_result['detail']->effective_date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                            $request->user_id
                        ]);
```