# $stmt->fetch() returns false when trying to call a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

When I'm trying to call my stored procedure using PHP, `$stmt->fetch();` returns `false` for some reason.

I've been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641726/get-return-value-from-sql-stored-procedure-using-php) for reference, but I can not seem to get it to work properly.

I have the following PHP code snippet that tries to call a stored procedure in my MySQL database:

```
$password = "pass";
$username = "name";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_login(:password,:username,@retval)");       
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':username',$username, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->execute();

var_dump($stmt); //prints "object(PDOStatement)[2] public 'queryString' => string 'CALL sp_login(:password,:username,@retval)' (length=42)"

$res = $stmt->fetch();

var_dump($res); //prints "boolean false"

$retval = $res['retval'];

var_dump($retval); //prints null
```

My stored procedure code:

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP PROCEDURE sp_login @@
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_login
(
IN in_password VARCHAR(255),
IN in_username VARCHAR(255),
OUT res INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    INTO res
    FROM användare
    WHERE lösenord = in_password
    AND användarnamn = in_username;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Why is `$stmt->fetch();` returning `false`? When i call the procedure directly in Mysql Workbench like this:

```
CALL sp_login('pass','name',@res);
SELECT @res;
```

It works as intended (it returns 1).

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014531/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedure-with-both-input-and-output-parameters-not) should help

Comment: @vmachan that did the trick. Thanks