# calling a DB Procedure having OUT parameter for each Row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am fetching a list of Employees with a column Status (Y/N) and want to pass its value to a procedure that will return me converted value. 
Procedure is working accurately. 
[image]

`call getStatusDescr('N',@p); select @p as Status;`

Can any one help me applying this procedure for each row in PHP Code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks friends, found the solution which is as under:
>   $vStatus = $row['Status'] ; is the part of another loop that is
>   fetching the record with status column.

```
$a = "localhost";
$b = "root";
$c = "";
$d = "test";
$conn1 = new mysqli($a, $b, $c, $d);
$call = $conn1->prepare('CALL GetStatusDescr(?, @pOut)');
$call->bind_param('s', $vStatus);
$call->execute();
$select = $conn1->query('SELECT @pOut');
$result1 = $select->fetch_assoc();
$vStatusOutDescr     = $result1['@pOut'];
```

Answer (score 0):

example for usage of procedures in php.

```
<?php         
  $connection = mysqli_connect("hostname", "user", "password", "db", "port");

  //run the store proc
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, 
     "CALL procName") or die("fail: " . mysqli_error());    

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
      echo $row[0] . " - " . + $row[1]; 
  }

?>
```

Comment: Sir, it is procedure with IN and OUT parameters and once I apply this code, it gives me error. Please share some example with parameters IN and OUT.

Comment: check this 1)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014531/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedure-with-both-input-and-output-parameters-not 
   2) http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/