# MYSQL TRIGGER PROCEDURE REMOTE_USER

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, procedure

Just getting started with the above.

It seems to be working fine, but I can not get my head around how I can pass a PHP value to the PROCEDURE.

I want to do an UPDATE or INSERT, TRIGGER AFTER, which will update 3 fields in the table.

Field 1 is a CONCAT of other fields works fine.
Field 2 is the current timestamp works fine.
Field 3 is the USER doing the update, but no idea how to get at the ENVIRONMENT variable REMOTE_USER - the MYSQL(CURRENT_USER) gives the database username not the actual login name of the user causing the TRIGGER.

Is it possible ?

mcl

Comment: Stored procedures in MySQL can have params.. then you can simply do `CALL SP($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])` (pseudo code) from PHP

Comment: Or you can use a MySQL user varables because they can be also used with in the trigger code.. `SET @remote_user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` (pseudo code query).. In the trigger code you can access that variable with `@remote_user`  example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jfr2w5XPUEaPNgqKkrEPgs/0

Comment: Wow - You do learn stuff here.  Never knew about db-fiddle.  The MYSQL user variable looks like the best way as this will be a TRIGGER with a PROCEDURE.  I expect I will be in trouble for saying Wow, but many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to add possibility to pass one new argument to your stored procedure.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014531/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedure-with-both-input-and-output-parameters-not) how you can pass arguments to procedure with php